# Swift + Firebase. Accessing current user's document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

My current firebase structure is Collection of Users which then have a subcollection of habits. For a given user, I want them to be able to add to their own collection of routines. however, running into an issue. When I run the function below, it just creates a separate user with a separate routine. How would I tie a new routine to a current authenticated user?

```
func addData(routineMsg: String){        
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let user = db.collection("users").document()
    let routine = db.collection("users").document("GzsHAHq1P0uXGdlYwF8P").collection("routines").document()
            routine.setData(["id": routine.documentID, "routine": routineMsg]) { err in
          if err != nil {
              print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
              return
          }
      }
  }
```

Right now, the code shows how I hard-code it to a certain document (GzsHAHq1P0uXGdlYwF8P), but would like to be able to determine the document dynamically by user

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear about what isn't working the way you expect.  Be specific about what you observe and how that differs from what you want.

Comment: firebase user id is separate from any document id in one of your collections. Often people tend to use it in such a way that it is coupled, so if you are indeed creating a document in your "users" collection for every firebase user with matching document and firebase user id, then you can just take your code and the id of your currently logged in firebase user. Or are you asking how to retrieve the currently logged in firebase user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let user = db.collection("users").document()
```

By not passing `document()` an argument, what you are doing is creating a new document reference with an auto-generated document ID. What you want to do is pass the method with a string that locates the user's document. Ideally, this would be the user's ID:

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
    return
}
let userDocRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
```

From there, to generate random document IDs in the subcollection, do what you were doing before:

```
func addData(routineMsg: String) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userDocRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
    let routineDocRef = userDocRef.collection("routines").document()

    routineDocRef.setData([
        "id": routineDocRef.documentID,
        "routine": routineMsg
    ]) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. You're the best +1